# When fetching data from database getting first index of a row only i want all data from each row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

am new to android and java... want to fetch all data from each row in sqlite.

```
public Cursor fetch() {
        dh = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = this.dh.query(TABLE_INVOICE, new String[]{ITEM_NAME, ITEM_PRICE, QTY, ITEM_TAX, BILL_NO, DATE, CUST_NAME, CUST_ADDR, INVOICE_TOT, GRAND_TOT, TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    return cursor;
}
```

data fetching:

```
Cursor cursor = datahandler.fetch();
//                        String response = datahandler.getInvoice(itemName,invoice,mprice,billno,mdate,qty);
        ITEM_NAME = cursor.getString(0).trim();
        ITEM_PRICE = cursor.getString(1).trim();
        QTY = cursor.getString(2).trim();
        ITEM_TAX = cursor.getString(3).trim();
        BILL_NO = cursor.getString(4).trim();
        DATE = cursor.getString(5).trim();
        CUST_NAME = cursor.getString(6).trim();
        CUST_ADDR = cursor.getString(7).trim();
        INVOICE_TOT = cursor.getString(8).trim();
        GRAND_TOT = cursor.getString(9).trim();
        TIME = cursor.getString(10).trim();
```

Comment: no changes @ Roger Gustavsson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `cursor.moveToNext()` repeatedly until it returns `false`, extracting data inbetween.

```
Cursor cursor = datahandler.fetch();

do {
    // extract data from cursor for current row
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

---

To protect against an empty `Cursor` you should also call -- and test the returned value from -- `moveToFirst()`. You call `moveToFirst()` when you retrieve the `Cursor`, but you never test the result.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // extract data from cursor for current row
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Must be related to something else then. I can't see any fault in the logic of the provided code.

Comment: the code is working... but only it can take the first rows of values

Comment: can i fetch single row from each column ? @Roger Gustavsson

Comment: used one method but i can't access some of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Return all items in a list from db.

```
public List<Records> fetch() {
    List<Records> records = new ArrayList<Records>();
    dh = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = this.dh.query(TABLE_INVOICE, new String[]{ITEM_NAME, ITEM_PRICE, QTY, ITEM_TAX, BILL_NO, DATE, CUST_NAME, CUST_ADDR, INVOICE_TOT, GRAND_TOT, TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ITEM_NAME = cursor.getString(0).trim();
            ITEM_PRICE = cursor.getString(1).trim();
            QTY = cursor.getString(2).trim();
            ITEM_TAX = cursor.getString(3).trim();

            records.add(new Records(ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,QTY,ITEM_TAX)); 
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return records;
}
```

and then `List<Records> records = db.fetch();`
loop through records list

Comment: Can you please post the problem you are getting.

Comment: Create a POJO class named Records with the required parameters as variables.